# how to set name of a field dynamically in openerp?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I am working on an openerp module . I want to make a field dynamically . I want to take a name of a field from user and then create a field to it . How this can be done ? Can I do it with fields.function to return name, char type ? Plz help

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want a dynamic field on the form/tree view or in the model?

If it is in the view then you override `fields_view_get`, call super and then process the returned XML for the form type you want adding in the field or manipulating the XML.  `ElementTree` is your friend here.

If you are talking about having a dynamic database field, I don't think you can and OpenERP creates a registry for each database when that database is first accessed and this process performs database refactoring at that time.  The registry contains the singleton model instances you get with self.pool.get...

To achieve this you will need to create some kind of generic field like `field1` and then in `fields_view_get` change the string attribute to give it a dynamic label.

Actually, a plan C occurs to me.  You could create a properties type of table, use a functional field to read the value for the current user and override `fields_view_get` to do the form.

Comment: hello dhana : how can we create table of type properties

Answer (score 0):

You can create Fields Dynamically by the help of class self.pool.get('ir.model.fields')
Use Create Function.